# Counting unique values in a column only when a different column has a criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a form submitting responses to a Google Sheet. Each response is a name and a date. I want to count the number of unique responses I got today.
Currently, I am able to count the responses for today but if Alex submitted the form twice, I count him twice. (for other reasons, I know that name values are unique.)
My current formula is below and I'd like to know how to adjust it. If it's helpful, here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bu5j4fdzl9jUs5u-k8x7HtrDtfVJ3YFdhcrj10S9gok/edit#gid=556646596) to a sample spreadsheet with mock data. See cell B4 on the sheet "Count of Responses"

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(1*INT('Form Responses'!C$2:C)=datevalue(B1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [COUNTUNIQUEIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9584429?hl=en):

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('Form Responses'!$B$2:$B,'Form Responses'!$C$2:$C,B1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that function existed.